# Why does `Microsoft.JScript` work in the Code behind but not within a `<% %>`?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why does `Microsoft.JScript` work in the Code behind but not within a `<% %>`?

I keep getting "CS0234: The type or namespace name 'JScript' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" Error but it doesn't make any sense at all. I can add the reference to `Microsoft.JScript.dll` and in the code behind it works, its just not working when I try to reference the thing in the web.config, or the page itself through the following code:

`<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.JScript" %>`

Web.Config

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.JScript" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

The Error I'm constantly getting is this:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'JScript' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue (http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0128776ff992970c-pi). Does this happen in a plain vanilla webapp also? If yes could you provide some context that might help reproduce the problem?

Comment: I'm currently using vs2010 Beta, is it possible that it's a bug in VS2010 or Framework 4.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the assembly, not just  the namespace. e.g.

```
<%@ Assembly name="Microsoft.JScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the `Microsoft.JScript` namespace at the top of the ASPX page, like this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.JScript" %>
```

You can also include it globally in Web.config:

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.JScript" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: all I got was "The directive 'using' is unknown."

Comment: I've tried both the `Import` and the `Web.config` version of it and still both give me "The type or namespace name 'JScript' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'"